# How do you change the owner of an Azure database

Tags: sql, database, azure, copy

I'm trying to make a copy of a database in Azure. This requires that the user logged in be the db_owner of the database.

Unfortunately the person who created the database has left and we don't have their login credentials and they don't remember them either.

Is there any way to change the db_owner in Azure databases?

Note: Doing `EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'login1User'` doesn't work for this as the actual owner account is needed to copy a database in Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to reset the password on the server (not the database).  When you click on "SQL Databases" tab on the portal, you'll go to a list of your databases.  On there there will be a 
"Server" column.  The entries in that column are hyperlinks.  Click on the server you don't know the password for.  on the Dashboard page for the server for the SQL Database  you'll see a "Reset Administrator Password" link on the right under "quick glance".

Once you do that you can log into the management console for the database and change the logins for the database with ALTER LOGIN

Answer (score 6):

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::<YourDatabaseName> to [NewOwner];
```

Comment: Welcome! It looks like this question had an accepted answer almost four years ago. I think the statement you mention would probably require [elevated permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql#AlterDB) they didn't have. Sometimes it can be useful to answer old questions (especially if they remained unanswered), but I think in this case they've got it covered. Cheers!

Comment: Agreed, this does not answer the actual question but this is solution for the question in subject :) <How do you change the owner of an Azure database>

Comment: I think you can change the database owner with this statement if you can log in as the server admin. This definitely answers the question in the subject line and it might answer the content of the question. It also helped me out quite a bit, so it gets an upvote from me.

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge there is no way to do this. Try looking in the former employees code for connections strings and hardcoded passwords.

You can also review this guide to see if there are any commands that may help you: [Managing Databases and Logins in Windows Azure SQL Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336235.aspx)